# crc32 decrypt short string

Tags: c#, vb.net, encryption, crc32

I am retrieving lists of crc32 hashes that contain names of files, not there contents.

I need to be able to decrypt the strings which are hashed names like "vacationplans_2010.txt"

which are less then 25 characters long.

is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

it is one-way hash function. It can't be decrypted.

Comment: Didn't downvote you, but notice: CRC is not a one-way hash function, it is just an insecure hash function.

Comment: No, it isn't... Google shall reveal this fact quite fast. For example, see criterions for cryptographic hash functions at Wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function

Comment: Don't confuse Cryptographic hash function and hash function. "A hash function is any well-defined procedure or mathematical function that converts a large, possibly variable-sized amount of data into a small datum, usually a single integer that may serve as an index to an array." - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function thats exactly what crc does

Comment: I figured that, thanks much. and brute forcing is not an option.

Comment: If I have the hash's Salt is it decryptable?

Comment: no. salt becomes part of the message that crc is calculated for.
consider function crc(x) = y. There is no inverse function. Now let's add salt: crc(x + salt) = y. Ok, you know y and salt. Is it better? No, because you still can find inverse of crc.

Answer (score 7):

Despite what other users answered, **CRC32 is not a cryptographic hash function**; it is meant for integrity checks (data checksums).
Cryptographic hash functions are often described as "one-way hash functions", CRC32 lacks the "one-way" part.

That being said, you should consider the following: since the set of all possible 25-characters-or-less filenames is more than 2^32, some file names are bound to have the same hash value. Therefore, it might be that for some of the CRC32 values you get - there will be several possible sources (file-names). You will need a way to determine the "real" source (i assume that human-decision would be the best choice, since our brain is a great pattern-recognition device, but it really depends on your scenario).

Several methods can be used to partially achieve what you are asking for. **Brute-force** is one of them (although, with 25 characters long file names, brute-force may take a while). A modified **dictionary attack** is another option. Other options are based on analysis of the CRC32 algorithm, and will require that you dive into the implementation details of the algorithm (otherwise you'll have a hard time understanding what you're implementing). For example, see this [article](http://www.codebreakers-journal.com/downloads/cbj/2004/CBJ_1_1_2004_Anarchriz_CRC_and_how_to_Reverse_it.pdf), or this [artice](http://sar.informatik.hu-berlin.de/research/publications/SAR-PR-2006-05/SAR-PR-2006-05_.pdf).

EDIT: definitions by Bruce Schneier (author of Applied Cryptography, among other things):

> One-way functions are relatively easy
>   to compute, but significantly harder
>   to reverse. … . In this context,
>   "hard" is defined as something like:
>   It would take millions of years to
>   compute x from f(x), even if all the
>   computers in the worlds were assigned
>   to the problem.
>
> A hash function is a function,
>   mathematical or otherwise, that takes
>   a variable length input string and
>   (called a pre-image) and converts it
>   to a fixed length (generally smaller)
>   output string (called a hash value).
>
> The security of a one-way hash
>   function is its one-wayness.

Comment: With this description, all hash algorithms are "lacking the one-way part", as you can always run brute-force on data to find which one(s) are producing the desired outcome. I would very much like you to describe why CRC32 lacks the "one-way" part, and, say, SHA384, doesn't.

Comment: I didn't define the "one-way" part. If you consider brute-force, then everything is insecure except for One Time Pads and derived algorithms (like some secret-sharing schemes).

The "one-way" part depends on the algorithm being "hard to reverse", meaning that given an image it is hard to learn anything about the source. Being "one-way" is not a well-defined criterion; it depends on current research and study of the algorithm. It can change, based on new knowledge spreading through the research community.

CRC was never built to be "one-way", the designers didn't try to make it that way.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function
see the difference?

Answer (score 3):

A [hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) like CRC32 calculates a simple value given (variable) input. The calculation is not reversible - i.e. you cannot reliably get the original value given only the hash.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, the general method is to find out the rule how u hash encryt result be the same as

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).